# Access query: count values >0

Tags: sql, ms-access, count

I have a table with a list of projects, their priority (split in 2 category of priority) and their status. The table has the following fields:

- project name
- status
- priority type A
- priority type B

I need to have a summary that is for each status, I would like to know the nummber of projects with priority of cat A > 0 and the number of project with priority of cat B > 0.
Building the query in the Structure view, the result SQL code is:

```
    SELECT MyTable.Status, Count(MyTable.[Priority CatA]) AS [CountCatA], Count(MyTable.[Priority CatB]) AS [CountCatB]
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY MyTable.Status
    HAVING (((Count(MyTable.[Priority CatA]))>0) AND ((Count(MyTable.[Priority CatB]))>0));
```

The results of this query is not what I want, it counts also Priority = 0.
So I tried to modify the SQL statements in the HAVING sentence in this way:

```
    HAVING (((MyTable.[Priority CatA])>0) AND ((MyTable.[Priority CatB])>0));
```

but the results was not good, the following error is given:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression  as part of an aggregate function. (Error 3122)"

Can someone help me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use a WHERE clause to restrict your results before the aggregation occurs. `HAVING` filters results AFTER aggregation. This is an important thing to understand with SQL.

Also, do your checking for `>0` inside the SELECT portion of the query for each field using an `iif()` function.  Something like the following should get you close:

```
SELECT status, sum(iif([priority catA]>0, 1, 0)) as [CountCatA], sum(iif([priority catB]>0, 1, 0)) as [CountCatB]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY status;
```

Those two calculated fields are checking to see if each respective `priority cat` are greater than `0`, if so it returns a `1`. That `1` is then summed, grouping on `status`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT MyTable.Status,
       SUM(IIF([Priority CatA] > 0, 1, 0)) as CountCatA,
       SUM(IIF([Priority CatB] > 0, 1, 0)) as CountCatB
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MyTable.Status;
```

Comment: Thank you also, as JNevill's answer, it has been very helpful"